# How to stop UAG authenticating requests via LDAP

Tags: firewall, microsoft-forefront, microsoft-forefront-2010

I want UAG to not authenticate ActiveSync requests before passing them on. I can see that at the moment the requests aren't being passed through because UAG checks with LDAP, which says that the user is unauthorized.

I basically want the UAG to just act as a reverse proxy.

"Require users to authenticate at session logon" (in advanced trunk configuration) is not enabled. Endpoint Access settings are all set to "Always".

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 1):

The above mentioned settings are enough. What was missing was the "activate" stage, performed by  clicking on the button next to the save button. It's not enough to save the settings or even reset IIS.